# Absolute positioned elemets blocking drag events

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, draggable, drag

I am trying to make slider, but I run into one issue.
The problem I am facing at is that absolute items block slider drag events.
I need somehow to allow dragging underlying image to be draggable through absolute positioned items.
Do you have a idea how to achieve that?
***MANY THANKS IN ADVANCE!***
Draggable="true" is not a solution because then that element became draggable (and ghost dragging image is visible).
Here is my code:
Codepen if you prefer: https://codepen.io/saksija/pen/MWgqNeJ

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="slider" ref="slider">
    <div class="slider-wrapper" ref="sliderContainer">
      <img ref="slide" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/really-wide-panoramic-sunrise-shot-260nw-35170.jpg">
      <div v-for="id in 2" :class="['subitem', 'o-'+id]"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue/Javascript:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    startX: 0,
    lastTranslate: 0,
    translate: 0
  }),
  watch: {
    translate(value) {
      this.$refs.sliderContainer.style.transform = `translate3d(${value}px, 0px, 0px)`;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dragStart(event) {
      this.startX = event.screenX;
    },
    dragEnd(event) {
      this.translate = this.lastTranslate;
    },
    dragMove(event) {
      if (event.screenX === 0) return;

      let distance = event.screenX - this.startX;
      let newTranslate = this.translate + distance;
      let sliderContainer = this.$refs.sliderContainer;

      this.lastTranslate = newTranslate;
      sliderContainer.style.transform = `translate3d(${newTranslate}px, 0px, 0px)`;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    let slider = this.$refs.slider;
    slider.addEventListener('dragstart', this.dragStart);
    slider.addEventListener('drag', this.dragMove);
    slider.addEventListener('dragend', this.dragEnd);
  }
})
```

CSS:

```
#app {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
.subitem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  user-select: none;
}
.subitem.o-1 {
  left: 3%;
}
.subitem.o-2 {
  left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Try setting the `z-index` of the slider to be greater than that of the absolute elements. Alternatively, add `pointer-events:none;` to the absolute elements.

Comment: I tried z-index, but without success. But pointer-events works as a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `.subitem` doesn't need to be interacted with, you can use `pointer-events:none;` on them. E.G:

```
.subitem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```